# Fill an Array with objects, read from a csv with a predefined name

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

(Working with Nodejs, csvjs)
I am trying to read a csv and parse it to get an Object for every row.
This is done via "csvjs".
For every row read, I create an object and add the information with Object.assign.

```
   fs.createReadStream('students.csv')
  .pipe(parse({
      delimiter: ",", 
      header:true,
      from_line:2,  
      encoding:'utf8',  
      objectMode:true,}))
  .on('data', function(dataRow) {
      //console.log(`DATAROW: ${dataRow}`)
      let data = dataRow.slice( )
      console.log(`DATA: ${data}`)
      const pros = {...data}
      Object.assign(pros,{'first_name' : pros[0]})[0]
      delete pros[0]
      Object.assign(pros,{'last_name' : pros[1]})[1]
      delete pros[1]
```

I am getting an object which I push into an array. ie.:

```
[{
first_name: '',
last_name: '',
name: ''
}]
```

The goal now is that every object becomes a nested object in an object with 'Contact', ie.:

```
{Contact:
  {
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    name: ''
  }
}
```

I am thinking, that maybe I can create a predefined object '{Contact:{ }}' and fill it with the cell read from the csv.

Comment: Could you please also show an example of what is in your csv so that we can run your code ?